# resize window function with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have font awesome icon only when the window size is under 960px so i add this condition if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 960px)").matches) and also when i resize the window over 960 this icon had to disappear and reappear when the window is resize under 960 so i have this code :

```
$(window).resize(function() {
 if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 960px)").matches) {
  $('li.has_children').prepend('<i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>');
    $('li.has_children').click(function (e) {
          $(this).children('i').toggleClass("fa-arrow-up  fa-arrow-down");
          $(this).children('ul.navi').toggle('1000');

           return false;
     });
    }
}).trigger("resize");
```

but the problem is that when i resize the window i had multiple icon instead of one

Comment: why not use css @media to do this

Comment: I first use media query with this a:after {
   color: black;
   content:  "\f107";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
} but the problem is that when i want to change the icon on click i can't get css after content with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting multiple font-awesome icons because you use the `jQuery.prepend()`. Each time you resize, the script is executed and prepend one more icon to `<li class="has_children">...</li>`.

To fix it, you will have to first remove it to make it disappear. The code will look like this

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 960px)").matches) {
        // attempt to remove the icon before prepending it
        $('li.has_children').children('i.fa.fa-arrow-up').remove();
        $('li.has_children').prepend('<i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>');
        $('li.has_children').click(function (e) {
            $(this).children('i').toggleClass("fa-arrow-up  fa-arrow-down");
            $(this).children('ul.navi').toggle('1000');

            return false;
        });
    }
}).trigger("resize");
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j2o62a45/1/`

Comment: i tested your code but i get multiple font-awesome icons every time i resize

Comment: @michellompret Sorry, I misunderstood the `jQuery.remove()`. The answer is updated and should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you end up with multiple icons because your code puts them there:

```
$('li.has_children').prepend('<i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>');
```

You can either move this live outside of the event so you end up with only one icon or you can remove the `".fa .fa-arrow-up"` from `'li.has_children'`.  Either works.

Comment: If i  move this live outside of the event the resize won't work . if i get the window smaller the icon won't appear and the toggle effect won't work.